# symfony2 login by username or email

Tags: symfony, email, authentication

I'm using the standard authentication mechanism of Symfony2 and I want to let the user use either his username or email to login, but I can't find out why it's not working. I've tested the repository class and it works as expected. I've followed this [how-to](http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/symfony2-login-username-e-mail/).

Here's my user provider class:

```php
<?php

namespace My\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository ,
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface ,
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
* UserRepository
*
* This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
* repository methods below.
*/
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface 
{
    function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u') ;
        return 
        $qb->select('u')
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->orx(
                $qb->expr()->like('u.username' ,':username') ,
                $qb->expr()->like('u.email' ,':username')
            )
        )
        //->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('u.enabled' ,'true') )
        ->setParameters(array('username' =>$username ) )        
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult() ;                  
    }

    function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername() );
    }

    function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === 'My\UserBundle\Entity\User';
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Be more detailed please.

Comment: Please move your solution to the problem from the question to an answer and accept it.

Comment: hello guys i cant accept my own answer :P till tomorrow

Comment: FFR, I found this to be a great guide: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.2.0/Resources/doc/logging_by_username_or_email.md#extending-the-usermanager-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well guys the thing is in my security.yml i had this

```
providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: My\UserBundle\Entity\User ,property : username}
```

so i had to take off that parameter `property :username`

Comment: According to the answers by Anand and David Barrat this seems like a hackish at-best-temporary fix, not a proper solution.

Answer (score 9):

I propose a more simple approach that **only requires to edit security.yml** file.

You must to create two diferent security providers but both using the same User class. The first has **username** as property and the second has **email** as property.

Then you create a **chain_provider** that includes the two  providers and use it in your firewall section

```
security:

    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [db_username, db_email]
        db_username:
            entity:
                class: MyUserBundle:User
                property: username
        db_email:
            entity:
                class: MyUserBundle:User
                property: email

    firewalls:

        default:
            anonymous: ~            
            provider: chain_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login
```

I don't know if this approach is a clean practice, but is fast, simple and it works ok.

Comment: I have not tested this yet, but looks like a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Taking off the **property: username** lets the **UserProviderInterface** load the user as expected when it logs in, but does not call the **refreshUser()** method as expected. I put in checks to see if it gets called but it doesn't.

The class that reloads the user on each access is **ContextListener::refreshUser(TokenInterface $token)** method. In this the interface iterates through the UserProviders and calls the refreshUser that first returns a non-null user.

I could make sure of this because, in the original load, I combine all different entities to make one SQL call instead of 7. And when the user reloads, it calls 7 times.

Also the method **EntityUserProvider::refreshUser()** doesn't call the repository's method and instead reloads from the database directly.

Comment: Adding the following code in **EntityUserProvider** class solves the refreshUser issue:

`if($this->repository instanceof UserProviderInterface) {
    return $this->repository->refreshUser($user);
}`

Comment: Editing Symfony seems like a big no-no, since it breaks the ability to update Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

Your provider class is correct, and you are correct that the problem is in security.yml, however, your solution is incorrect.

According to the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#authenticating-someone-with-a-custom-entity-provider), your security.yml file should look like this:

```
security:
# ...
providers:
    administrators:
        entity: { class: MyUserBundle:User }
```

Notice that the class is defined as the Bundle, not the direct class.
The way you have your code right now, symfony is completly ignoring your repository class until you define your security.yml correctly. And as @Anand pointed out, just removing the property does not invoke refreshUser. However, it looks like if you are using your own Repository, you do not need to define the property (since it's being defined in your query).